# How do I fit in GCS nested JSON into BQ Table

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the created BQ table according to the Nested JSON data.
But I facing schema error "Field enb_location is type RECORD but has no schema"
Below is the schema of the BQ table and the actual Data. Can you help what am I missing in the schema??

Data:

"enb_location": {
"coordinates": [
-111.89160399999999,
40.873279
],
"crs": {
"properties": {
"name": "EPSG:4326"
},
"type": "name"
},
"type": "Point"
}

BQ Table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With schema, data and load command below I was able to load the data.

You need to define the schema and run the `bq load` command as below

```
--Data--
{"end_location":{"coordinates":[-111.89160399999999,40.873279],"crs":{"properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"},"type":"name"},"type":"Point"}}

--Load command--
bq --location=australia-southeast1 load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON YOUR_DATASET.PROJECT_ID gs://YOUR_GCS_LOCATION_WHERE_DATA/sample_json_data.json sample_json_schema.json --this is the schema file below on your local directory


--Schema--

[
  {
    "name": "end_location",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "coordinates",
        "type": "FLOAT",
        "mode": "REPEATED"
      },
      {
        "name": "crs",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "properties",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "type",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "type",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[image: Dataloaded in table]

Comment: Thank you Bihag, Appreciated your efforts!